# Area control of a legend box in a plot in R

Tags: r, plot, legend

[image]

Here I attach one picture where legend box is outside of the plot area. How can I control legend box according to x direction? Here I use the following code to create the legend:

```
par(xpd=TRUE)
legend(x=16.8,y=2600,legend=c("North","East","West","North_East","North_West","East_West"), 
lwd=2,col=c("red", "blue", "green","black","pink","Orange"))
```

`x=16.8` means legend box will start from here. Can I set end point of legend box in the x direction ? Please help me to plot a legend box within the figure.

Comment: Review the `x.intersp` argument in `legend()`, it will assist with making the legend not as wide. As for controlling your legend along the x-axis, also review the `inset` argument.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. With x.intersp - I can control distance between line and text in a legend box. I also try y.intersp - I can control distance between two legend's text in the direction of y axis. 
Now my question is how to reduce line length in a legend box so that overall box will be on plot. I am expecting some more help regarding inset.

Comment: If I want to divide my text in to two lines, then what should I have to do ?

Answer (score 0):

To fix your problem, you have to know how large your `legend` is and fix the x-axis range accordingly. To do this, you need to plot an empty plot and empty legend and assign the legend to an object. This way, you an access the dimensions of the legend. You then redraw the plot with a custom x-axis range with `xlim`.

```
#Generate data
x   <- seq(0,22,length=1000)
y   <- dnorm(x,mean=10, sd=0.5)*4000

#Plot empty plot, get legend size
par(xpd=TRUE)
plot(x,y, type="n", axes=F, xlab="", ylab="")
my.legend.data <-legend(x=16.8,y=2600,legend=c("North","East","West","North_East","North_West","East_West"),
lwd=2,col=c("red", "blue", "green","black","pink","Orange"), plot=FALSE)

#plot chart with custom xlim that will fit legend
my.x.range <-c(min(x),my.legend.data$rect$left+my.legend.data$rect$w)
plot(x,y, type="l", lwd=1, xlim=my.x.range)
legend(x=16.8,y=2600,legend=c("North","East","West","North_East","North_West","East_West"),
lwd=2,col=c("red", "blue", "green","black","pink","Orange"))
```

[image]